iOS Simulator - Error fetching bundle record for scheme approval when using deeplink with https
I have been having issues after upgrading the xcode from 14 to 15. Currently using Version 15.4 (15F31d).
Our universal links aren't working on the iOS simulator when using https as schema it does when we use the alias. Also real devices the universal links are working just fine.
Doesn't work:
xcrun simctl openurl booted "https://..."
It works:
xcrun simctl openurl booted "appName://..."
So I've started investigate as much I can so I found using Console from Instruments the below logs:
Timestamp   Type    Process Subsystem   Category    Message 
00:13.297.936   Default CoreSimulatorBridge (17644) CoreSimulatorBridge Default Opening URL (https://...) with com.apple.mobilesafari   
00:13.299.259   Default lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    default Found application: com.apple.mobilesafari to handle url scheme: https   
00:13.299.281   Default lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    default Found application: com.appName.appName to handle url scheme: https  
00:13.299.896   Info    lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    datasep application record search init. Node: bundleID: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorBridge itemID: 0   
00:13.299.926   Info    lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    datasep application record search init. Node: bundleID: com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorBridge itemID: 0   
00:13.299.951   Error   lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    default Error fetching bundle record for scheme approval: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={\_LSLine=1608, \_LSFunction=runEvaluator}   
00:13.299.961   Info    lsd (17657) com.apple.launchservices    datasep application record search init. Node: bundleID: com.apple.mobilesafari itemID: 0    
00:13.302.047   Default lsd (17657) com.apple.FrontBoard    Common  \[FBSSystemService\]\[0x3397\] Sending request to open "com.apple.mobilesafari" 
00:13.302.658   Default SpringBoard (17618) com.apple.FrontBoard    Common  \[FBSystemService\]\[0x3397\] Received request to open "com.apple.mobilesafari" with url "https:\<private\>" from lsd:17657 on behalf of CoreSimulatorBr:17644. 
00:13.302.884   Default SpringBoard (17618) com.apple.FrontBoard    Common  \[FBSystemService\]\[0x3397\] Trusting entitled client CoreSimulatorBr:17644.

So the Found application: com.appName.appName to handle url scheme: https I would assume that means the app can open but down below I get the error Error fetching bundle record for scheme approval: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=1608, _LSFunction=runEvaluator} which I cannot figure out why's that and googling I cannot find anything about it. Is there a way I could potentially debug somehow to figure that out?
Thank you,
